# Any way to bypass the password check here?

Tags: c, security, passwords, exploit

```
static int checkPassword(char* user_pw) {

  char dummy[128];
  int accept = 0;
  char pw[8];
  char len;
  char* correct_pw = "xf35+";
  memset(pw, 0, sizeof(pw));
  memset(dummy, 0, sizeof(dummy));

  len = strlen(user_pw);
  if (len < 8) {
    strcpy(pw, user_pw);
  }
  if (strcmp(pw, correct_pw) == 0) {
    accept = 1;
  }
  return accept;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Where argv[3] should be password
  // ...
  if (strlen(argv[3]) > 128) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Password is too long!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if (checkPassword(argv[3]) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Password is incorrect!\n");
    return 1;
  }
  // ...
}
```

The passwrod here is hard-coded but is there any way to bypass the password check?
I noticed that "len" is declared as a char but still don't know exactly how to solve this

Comment: Hint: `char` can be a signed type.

Comment: What do you mean "bypass" exactly? Obviously the code is written to check a password, so actually "bypassing" the password would require re-writing the code, or hacking the final executable. What are you really trying to accomplish?  And BTW, `checkPassword()` can be simplified to just `return strcmp(user_pw, correct_pw) == 0;`, you don't need everything else in it

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The code is *meant* to check a password... the question is whether it will actually do it, or if it can be exploited.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I disagree.  At the very least, at the level of standard C, it is possible to provide input for which the code has Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I was trying not to give it away, but what happens if `char` is a signed 8-bit type and `argv[3]` is exactly 128 characters long (not counting the trailing nul)?

Comment: @NateEldredge Nevermind, I see what you are referring to now - `char len` instead of `int len`, causing a buffer overflow of `pw` when `strlen(user_pw) > 127`. Simplify `checkPassword()` like I described earlier and the buffer overflow goes away.

Comment: But... but... but... That is unethical! No one would exploit a bug in the code to acquire access to a system. That would just be wrong on so many levels. What kind of animals are these people?

Comment: got it now thx!